# popup redirecting and gives a message in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, popup

I'm making a project in asp.net and i need a popup to show a message and redirecting to a website.
I!m using a function to do this like:

```
 private void btnRedirect_Click()
    {
        string message = "Sucsessfully saved. You are redirecting to main page";
        string url = "IssuesList.aspx";
        string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
        script += message;
        script += "');";
        script += "window.location = '";
        script += url;
        script += "'; }";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", script, true);
    }
```

but on top of the popup there is line like: message from webpage on localhost:19654

I dont want it so is there any way to make a popup witout that message?
Thank you.

I tried this one; but it didn't show message and redirect

```
 private void btnRedirect_Click()
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Record saved successfully.');window.location='IssuesList.aspx';", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, it is a browser specific feature, also it is a way to view that the alert you are seeing is from the page you think are, it is to prevent phishing.

But, there are alternatives like [jQuery-confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) which should work for what you want